# Safely move my blog?

Tags: .htaccess

My blog is currently located at:

```
example.com/blog
```

with posts being something like:

```
example.com/blog/my-post
```

I want to edit my htaccess file so anyone that accesses

```
example.com/blog/my-post
```

would end up at:

```
example.com/my-post
```

How can I do this with an htaccess file?

**UPDATE**

Right now I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

That will forward any non-www traffic to www. However, I need to modify this to support /blog as well. I don't think my syntax is right:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/blog$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

?

Comment: Can you show your existing `/blog/.htaccess`?

Comment: No, not yet. I added some code to show how far I've gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `/blog` using `HOST_NAME` variable.

Have your htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

**This assumes there is no `.htaccess` in `/blog/` directory**. However if it is there for some reason then use this rule as **first rule** in `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```